# Is 1194 the best and safest port for a VPN?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, port

When installing OpenVPN, there are options to set the port to a different port than default: default is 1194.  Is it safer to use a random port number (such as a port above 4000)?  Because 1194 is the default, it might set off red flags when the port is seen to be accessed constantly by ISPs, and the ISPs might generate complaints?

Comment: It won't make a difference - all that matters is the encryption used (in terms of security). If the ISPs see that all your traffic is going through one port (be that 1194 or another) they'll probably deduce that you're using a VPN anyway. 1194 is just the default for a lot of VPNs.

Comment: Also your ISP probably wouldn't generate complaints at all (unless of course the use of VPNs/other circumvention methods are banned in your region)

Comment: see if it's helpful to you:https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/advanced-option-settings-on-the-command-line/#:~:text=By%20default%20the%20OpenVPN%20Access,443%20as%20a%20fallback%20method.